# Which HTML5 player with Flash fallback have a common javascript API

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, html, html5-video

As far as I can find on Google the only HTML5 player with flash that uses the same javascript API for both player is http://mediaelementjs.com.

I have a very dynamic site layout where most other HTML elements on the page should change state according to these video event:

- beforeLoad
- onload
- onPlay
- onPause
- onStop
- onEnd

Jquery is used to change the states so a HTML5 that works well with Jquery is preferred.

Are there other that do the job better or offer more event control? 
If mediaelementjs is the only one out there, I would like to hear your experiance with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://www.jplayer.org

Here's the documentation page: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/

Comment: Thats a pretty nice player, nice to have all the controls in HTML.
It's great to have all that documentation.
Is it simple to skin?

Comment: There are some examples of skins and it is customizable to have non-default css selectors: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-skins

Answer (score 1):

Or [DarkOnyx player](http://darkonyx.web-anatomy.com/en), two identical HTML5/Flash players - the same JavaScript API. Everything is based on Event-Listener model. [Documentation is here](http://darkonyx.web-anatomy.com/en/Documentation).